# Error local variable 'node' referenced before assignment in my linked list implementation?

Tags: python, linked-list

So I implemented this linked list and this is my node class:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item,next):
        self.item=item
        self.next=next
```

and this is my get_node method:

```
def _get_node(self, index):
    if index>0:
        assert index <len(self), "Index out of bound"
        node=self.head
        for _ in range(index):
            node=node.next
     return node
```

And this is my append method

```
def append(self,item):
    node=0
    if self.count==0:
        self.head=Node(item,self.head)


    else:
        index=len(self)
        node=self._get_node(index-1)
        node.next=Node(item,node.next)
    self.count+=1
```

However, I keep getting this error local variable node referenced before assignment whenever I try to append a second item?Any help will be appreciated. I'm just a beginner at python

EDIT:Okay this is the actual traceback exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\task1unitTest.py", line 23, in <module>
   a_list.append(2)
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\task3.py", line 87, in append
  node=self._get_node(index-1)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\task3.py", line 26, in _get_node
  return node
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'node' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: It helps to post the actual exception traceback, not just a paraphrase of it.

Comment: Anyway: What happens if you call `self._get(0)`? Then `index>0` is not true, so you don't assign anything to `node`. But you try to `return node` anyway. Hence the error. Now trace what happens when you try to append when `len(self) == 1`, and it should be obvious what goes wrong.

Comment: What is happening is if the index is zero for the function to return `node` there is nothing. You may want to consider adding `node = None` at starting of the function `_get_node`. Taking a look at [better reference implementation](https://dbader.org/blog/python-linked-list) might help

Comment: I thought there must be a canonical question for this, but everything that seems related is actually about mixing up global and local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this method:

```
def _get_node(self, index):
    if index>0:
        # node only gets assigned her
    return node
```

What if you call it with `index==0`? When you try to `return node`, it doesn't have a value.

So, why does it only happen when you try to append a second node? When you append the first node, `self.count==0`, so you never call `_get_node`. When you append the second node, `self.count==1`, so you go into the `else`. And then, since `len(self)` is 1, `index-1` ends up a 0. So you call `node=self._get_node(0)`.

If this isn't obvious, you may want to use an interactive visualizer like [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to step through your code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint